# Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. Cause: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource mappers/User.xml

Tags: xml, spring, maven, intellij-idea, mybatis

Getting

> org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException java.io.IOException: Could
> not find resource User.xml

Project structure has `User.xml` at `src/main/resources/mappers/User.xml` and resources is marked as resources root in intellij idea

`mybatis-config.xml` has the following mapper configuration : `mapper resource="mappers/User.xml"`

[Screenshot for the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtkEi.png)